# ng-if is not working even though I have expected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-if is not working even though I have expected value.

In the code below  attribute `isAutoCompleteField` is true. But if I am using `ng-if` it is not getting removed from UI. If anyone know means please tell.

```
<input test="attribute.isAutoCompleteField" attribute="attribute" type="text" ng-model="[attribute.tagName]">
```

Comment: could you add the ng-if code that is not working?

Comment: <input ng-if="attribute.isAutoCompleteField" attribute="attribute" type="text" ng-model="[attribute.tagName]">

Answer (score 0):

to hide an element try `ngShow` or `ngHide`

`<input ng-show="attribute.isAutoCompleteField" attribute="attribute" type="text" ng-model="[attribute.tagName]">`

Comment: <input ng-show="attribute.isAutoCompleteField" attribute="attribute" type="text" ng-model="[attribute.tagName]"> 
While hiding time i need to show another element. That time it is not showed another element.

Comment: you can use the same scope variable to show and hide different element. so you could use: `<input ng-hide="attribute.isAutoCompleteField"  type="text" ng-model="test1">` and `<input ng-show="attribute.isAutoCompleteField" type="text" ng-model="test2">`

Answer (score 0):

That is because [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) create a new scope, so `attribute.isAutoCompleteField` would be outside of your controller's scope. Try using [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) instead to show/hide the element.